# How can I make Two-way binding of a checkbox in client side Blazor work with a view model

Tags: mvvm, two-way-binding, blazor-client-side

My checkbox in Blazor client side is only working one way, from UI to the view model, but not the other.
I also have a Windows application using the exact same view model, where the two-way binding works perfectly.

The view model is placed in a separate project, which is referenced from both the Blazor client side appliction and the Windows application.

I have implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in my view model.

The observed behaviour is:

1. When I start my Blazor application, the UI does not reflect the value from the view model and database. If I start my Windows application, it does.
2. If I change the value in the database, my Windows application UI will get updated within 30 seconds, but my Blazor will not.
3. If I click on the check box in the UI, my view model and database will get updated, both in Blazor and the Windows application.

So, what am I doing wrong in the Blazor client side application?

My Blazor view is quite simple:

```
@using ViewModels
@inject IViewModel ViewModel

<div class="bordered">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox1" @bind="@ViewModel.BooleanValue" />
    <label for="chkbox1">Boolean Value</label>
</div>
```

My view mode:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public interface IViewModel : IViewModelBase
    {
        bool BooleanValue{ set; get; }
    }

    public class ViewModel : ViewModelBase, IViewModel
    {
        private bool booleanValue;
        private readonly IDomain domainLayer;

        public ViewModel(IDomain domainLayer)
        {
            this.domainLayer = domainLayer;
            PropertyChanged += HandleDomainLayerUpdateOnPropertyBooleanValueChanged;
            DomainModelChanged += HandleViewModelUpdateOnDomainModelChanged;
            OnDomainModelChanged();
            UpdateFromDomain();
        }

        // Function to make the system check for database changes every 30 seconds
        private void UpdateFromDomain()
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    OnDomainModelChanged();
                    await Task.Delay(30000);
                }
            });
        }

        public bool BooleanValue
        {
            set
            {
                booleanValue= value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BooleanValue");
            }
            get { return booleanValue; }
        }

        private async void HandleDomainLayerUpdateOnPropertyBooleanValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await domainLayer.SetBooleanValueAsync(executed);
        }

        private async void HandleViewModelUpdateOnDomainModelChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BooleanValue = await domainLayer.GetBooleanValueAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the UI to know about the change in `BooleanValue` you will need to call `StateHasChanged()` this will trigger a render of the UI.

You have mentioned that you are using `INotifyPropertyChanged`, a way to do this is to add this line in your Razor page code.

```
ViewModel.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => StateHasChanged();
```

Then the changes to the UI will be rendered when your view model property has changed.